# Algorithm for Weather Prediction and alert generation

Tags: data-mining

I am new to machine learning and working on a project in which I collect environment data like temperature, humidity, dust, light intensity , Carbon mono oxide and rain data through sensors and send it to cloud. Now I want to generate alerts on the basis of conditions to occur in coming days. What machine learning algorithms should I use for this? I was working on neural network but can we predict the temperature on the basis of temperature past days ? I tried to do that but I tried to take temperature as X(input) and what should I take "Y"(output matrix)? Can neural network be only used when some X variable is dependent on some OTHER Y variable? Which algorithm would be most suitable for my work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Weather forecasting and alerting requires huge simulations.

I suggest you first study meteorology. Then you buy a supercomputer (some if the largest are used in weather forecasting, for a reason) and run your own climate models.